# MvxGridView ItemClick not Firing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm struggling to do something which seems trivial.

I have an MvxGridView like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <Mvx.MvxGridView
    android:id="@+id/subjects_gv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/assigned_subject_view"
    app:MvxBind="ItemClick ShowSubjectFeatures;ItemsSource Subjects;"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:clickable="true"
  local:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
  local:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
    <ImageView
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:id="@+id/iv_subject_image"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/english" />
    <TextView
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:id="@+id/tv_subject_Name"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textAllCaps="true"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:maxLines="2"
      android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
      android:textSize="@dimen/very_small_text"
      local:MvxBind="Text Name" />
  </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And here is the viewmodel

```
private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;
        private readonly ISubjectsService _subjectsService;

        public SubjectsViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService, ISubjectsService subjectsService)
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;
            _subjectsService = subjectsService;
        }

        public MvxObservableCollection<SubjectModel> Subjects { get; set; } = new MvxObservableCollection<SubjectModel>();

        public MvxCommand<SubjectModel> ShowSubjectFeatures
        {
            get
            {
                // Navigate to subject details viewmodel
                return new MvxCommand<SubjectModel>(async subject => await NavigateToFeatures(subject));
            }
        }

        public override async Task Initialize()
        {
            var response = await _subjectsService.GetAssignedSubjects();
            Subjects.AddRange(response.Subjects);
        }

        private async Task NavigateToFeatures(SubjectModel model)
        {
            await _navigationService.Navigate<SubjectFeatureViewModel, int>(model.Id);
        }
```

The issue is when I click on a grid item the command isn't triggered.
Other info, the gridview is displayed in a fragment and the SubjectFeaureView is also a fragment so it will be navigation from a fragment to fragment. I don't think that should be an issue, tho. What am I missing? I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Why do you have `android:clickable="true"` on your CardView?

Comment: @Cheesebaron because I want it to be clickable, or isn't clickable by default. Just noticed I have it on the RelativeLayout as well, not needed there tho.

Comment: If the click command isn't fired it is because something soaked up the click event and it is not passed down to the Adapter for the GridView.

Comment: Good point, just don't know what could be soaking it up.

Comment: Use the Layout Inspector in Android Studio to dump the view hierarchy and check your layout

Comment: Also if you are just showing two columns of data I highly recommend using RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager instead. It is much more performant

Comment: Ok, I will install Android Studio checkout the Layout Inspector. I'm using Gridview cos I thought it will be "easier" to use and since there will be no more than 4 rows so I thought Gridview will suffice.

Comment: @Cheesebaron finally circled back to this part of the project. The Layout Inspector didn't help, but it is good to know about that tool. Thanks for saying something about android:clickable="true" cos that was the problem, removing that line fixed my problem, imagine that.. I have a long way to go. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing android:clickable="true" fixed my problem.

Comment: Congrats, could you please mark your reply as an answer so that others who have similar questions will get help from here?  Thanks . :)